# How to fix ogr2ogr: command not found

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, windows, anaconda, bash

I am an intern and was told to run this script, but I'm having some problems getting it to work and no one in my department has been able to offer any advice.

I am using Windows 10 and running the script using a WSL bash command inside the `miniconda3` command prompt in an environment that I installed `GDAL` in using `conda-forge`.

The script works until it runs into `ogr2ogr`, when it returns `ogr2ogr: command not found.`

I have tried to add `ogr2ogr` to the path, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, and didn't think I would need to because `GDAL` was installed in the miniconda environment.

I attached the script below with the sensitive information removed.

How can I get `ogr2ogr` to work here?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "${PG_CONNECTION_STRING}" ]]; then
  echo "Environment variable PG_CONNECTION_STRING is required and must contain the database connection string."
  exit 1
fi

# Set variable with layer configuration.
read -r -d '' layer_config << EOM
{
  "pedestrian.sidewalk_network_score_hexagon": {
    "target_name": "aggregated",
    "description": "Sidewalk network ADA compliance and condition scores aggregated to half-mile hexagons",
    "minzoom": 0,
    "maxzoom": 12
  },
  "pedestrian.sidewalk_score": {
    "target_name": "sidewalk",
    "description": "Sidewalk ADA compliance and condition scores",
    "minzoom": 13,
    "maxzoom": 14
  },
  "pedestrian.curb_ramp_score": {
    "target_name": "curb_ramp",
    "description": "Curb ramp ADA compliance and condition scores",
    "minzoom": 13,
    "maxzoom": 14
  },
  "pedestrian.crosswalk_score": {
    "target_name": "crosswalk",
    "description": "Crosswalk ADA compliance and condition scores",
    "minzoom": 13,
    "maxzoom": 14
  },
  "pedestrian.pedestrian_signal_score": {
    "target_name": "pedestrian_signal",
    "description": "Pedestrian signal ADA compliance and condition scores",
    "minzoom": 13,
    "maxzoom": 14
  }
}
EOM

# Prompt the user for the year.
echo "Please enter the year being exported:"
read year

echo "$year.mbtiles"

# Convert the layers to map tiles.
ogr2ogr -f MBTILES "$year.mbtiles" \
  PG:"$PG_CONNECTION_STRING" \
  -oo TABLES='pedestrian.sidewalk_network_score_hexagon,pedestrian.sidewalk_score,pedestrian.curb_ramp_score,pedestrian.crosswalk_score,pedestrian.pedestrian_signal_score' \
  -dsco NAME="$year Sidewalk Network Inventory and Assessment" \
  -dsco DESCRIPTION="$year compliance and condition scores from the Sidewalk Network Inventory and Assessment" \
  -dsco MINZOOM=0 \
  -dsco MAXZOOM=14 \
  -dsco CONF="$layer_config"
```

Comment: brute force answer: give the full path to the executable

Comment: that's a good idea, just tried it and got a new error. `C:/Users/USERNAME/Miniconda3/envs/pygdal/Library/bin/ogr2ogr.exe: No such file or directory`.

Comment: There is also a pythonic way by using the ogr2ogr library, see examples in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_ogr2ogr_lib.py.

Answer (score 1):

Pass full path inside double quotes like this:

```
"C:/Users/USERNAME/Miniconda3/envs/pygdal/Library/bin/ogr2ogr.exe" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it left me the same error. Not sure why it is unable to find the directory. Could it be because I am running it in the conda virtual environment?

Comment: @calmsheep Are you running it in Docker or a chroot enviroment?

Comment: I'm running it in a virtual environment in Miniconda. I write the command bash, to activate the linux environment, and then I call the file name. Is the linux env (through WSL) messing up my path? Thank you for the help I'm still pretty new to running shell scripts on Windows.